# New internal WD HDD not being detected

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bios, hardware-detection

I have two rather old desktop computers, one is DDR2 with 500Gb Hdd (with Win 10) and other is Dell optiplex 7010 without HDD. I bought a new 320Gb Hard disk (but with product date: 2009 WD) for second PC, but my system doesn't detect it. The first PC also not detect it at all, neither as primary nor secondly with the following error in computer system information on the first page of Boot:

> `sec slave Hard disk error`

I tried to change Dell BIOS SATA setting from `ACHI` to `ATA`, and something like `SATA0=     0Gb` appeared in System information part of BIOS, but still my system can't detect it during windows install with the following warning/error

> `We couldn't find any drives, to get a storage driver click load driver.`

I have watched several YouTube videos (from changing SATA cable to changing BIOS options) but not helpful. I also tried using live Ubuntu, but HDD doesn't appeared there too. I heard that I should add some jumper to HDD to work with. Is that correct? I am not familiar with this type of settings.

Any idea to get ride of this problem?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the HDD to another device to be sure it's in good state?

Comment: Isn't my first computer considered as another device?

Comment: Yes, of course but since they are both rather old, I would start checking it on a more recent station to fully exclude disk failure.

Comment: According to the [Optiplex 7010 Technical Guidebook](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/optiplex_7010_technical_guidebook.pdf), it has two SATA 2 ports and also two SATA 3 ports. Check that the port you used suits the disk.

Comment: Sorry @harrymc, I forgot to mention it that my dell is a mini case and I have tried all 3 SATA ports.

Comment: So both drives are not detected in both machines? Are they getting power? can you try new sata data cables?

Comment: New HDD has power. I have tried with 3 SATA cable. one of them is my other PC SATA that is fine. which both drives?